# Как отсортировать строки по длине слова регулярным выражением Notepad++

Tags: сортировка, notepad++

ДО:

```
aaa
aaaa
aaaaaa
a
aa
aaaa
aa
a
```

Нужно:

```
а
аа
ааа
аааа
ааааа
аааааа
```

Каким образом можно отсортировать по количеству букв

Comment: скопировать в эксель и отсортировать

Comment: @teran это если есть средства на Эксель, он так то не бесплатный

Comment: @teran эксель это очень просто. Нужен способ нотепад

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39294895/how-to-sort-a-list-of-column-by-character-length-in-notepad

Comment: @DiD гугл таблицы никто не отменял

Comment: На баше тоже просто, как и в экселе. `cat ./file.txt | while read row; do printf '%04d %s\n' $(wc -c<<< "$row") "${row}"; done |sort | perl -pe 's/^[0-9]+ //g' > ./sorted.txt` - но баш не нотпад

Comment: Еще вот так можно через awk `cat ./file.txt | awk '{ print length, $0 }' | sort -n -s | cut -d" " -f2- > ./sorted.txt`

Comment: а вот так можно используя sed `cat ./file.txt | while read -r line; do builtin printf "${#line}@%s\n" "$line";done | sort -n | sed -u 's/^[^@]*@// > ./sorted.txt`

Comment: Нотпад. Это как нейронные сети в столбик считать. Да что ваш блокнот вообще умеет. Давно бы уже использовали https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor) + https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux. Ну, ведь удобно же. И мозги держит в тонусе.

Comment: @DiD снимаю шляпу) отличное решение

Answer (score 0):

Edit -> Line Operations -> Sort …

Comment: так сортирует по алфавитному порядку, а нужно чтобы сортировал по количеству букв

Comment: Для вашего примера разницы нет.

Comment: спасибо Вам за внимание. Ваш способ мне не подходит

Answer (score 0):

Мы можем воспользоваться тем, что спец символы ставятся выше при сортировке, чем другие символы.
Можно попробовать решить эту задачу с помощью плагина `TextFX`. Для начала его нужно установить из менеджера плагинов:
`Plugins` `->` `Plugins Admin...`
[image: установка плагина TextFX]

***Шаг первый*** Добавляем порядковый номер в начале, чтобы сохранить оригинальный порядок строк, если будут строки одинаковой длинны.
Ставим курсор в самое начало и жмём `Edit` `->` `Column Editor...` (Комбинация клавиш `Alt` + `C`)
Указываем `Start` = 1 `Increase by` = 1 и обязательно указываем `Include Leading Zeros`
[image: Добавляем нумерацию строк]

***Шаг второй*** Делаем отступ в виде спец символов
Нужно добавить спец символы в начало строки. Их количество должно быть равно разнице между самой длинной и самой короткой строкой. Если есть строка 3 символа и строка 59 сиволов, то нужно добавить 56 спец символов.
Жмём `Edit` `->` `Column Editor...` (Комбинация клавиш `Alt` + `C`)
[image: добавляем отсутпы спецсимволов]

***Шаг третий*** Обрезаем строки до одинаковой длинны
Пользуемся регулярным выражением:

```
^.*(.{26})$
```

для того, чтобы обрезать строки до одинаковой длинны.
Выделяем самую короткую строку и запоминаем её длинну.
Переходим в Find/Replace (Комбинация клавиш `Ctrl`+ `H`) и в `Find what:` указываем

```
^.*(.{26})$
```

Где вместо 26 - длинна вашей строки. В `Replace with...` указываем `$1`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Шаг четвёртый*** Сортируем строки
Выделяем весь текст (Комбинация клавиш `Ctrl` + `A`) Идём в `TextFx` `->` `TextFx Tools` `->` `Sort lines case sensitive (at column)`
Если хотите отсортировать от самой длинной к самой короткой отметьте `Text FX` `->` `TextFX Tools` `->` `+ Sort ascendin`
[image: сортируем получившиеся строки]

***Шаг пятый*** Удаляем ненужные спец символы
Используем ещё одно регулярное выражение:

```
^_*\d{2}
```

Переходим в Find/Replace (Комбинация клавиш `Ctrl`+ `H`) и в `Find what:` вставляем следующее

```
^_*\d{2}
```

где вместо числа два нужно указать количество цифр в номере строки (в моём примере у меня двухзначная нумерация строк, значит я указываю 2).
[image: результат сортировки]

Получаем строки, отсортированные по длинне.
Вместо спецсимвола `_` можно использовать любой символ, который не встречается в ваших строках. (Нужно будет немного подправить регулярные выражения.)

Comment: Почему не указан источник?